# Difference between grep [p]attern and grep pattern

Tags: regex, unix, grep

AFAIK `pattern` and `[p]attern` matches the same text. But i have seen the usage of `grep [p]attern` in lot of places. Could anyone explain the differences between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Both should be the same, square brackets are used in regular expressions to denote sets, but set with just one element is the same as the element alone.

Comment: With the notable difference that in `ps | grep [p]attern` the grep won't show up in the process list. So this is useful in situations where you want a pattern which doesn't match itself.

Comment: @tripleee any docs?, i understand that it filters the `grep process` from the process list, but how does it differentiates the `grep process` from others.

Comment: It doesn't "differentiate the grep process", it looks for p-a-t-t... which luckily does not match on g-r-e-p-space-[-p-]-a-t-t... As for documentation, I guess I might have picked this up from one of the `comp.unix.shell` FAQs once upon a time - http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-10.html was the closest I could find.

Comment: so `grep [p]attern doesn't match grep [p]attern`. Thanks :)